# ERROR: Unable to reinitialize the system at t = 12085.732` within specified tolerances

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem solving this system of differential equations Does anyone know why this happens?

NDSolve::reinitfail: Unable to reinitialize the system at t = 12085.732303153314` within specified tolerances.

Here, my code

```
m = 1*10^-3;  (*mass*)
l = 1*10^-8    ;  (*cosmology constant*)
G = 1;
U[ϕ_] := 1/2 m^2*ϕ^2;  (*scalar field*)
D[U[ϕ[t]], ϕ[t]];
den := (1/2 (ϕϕ'[t])^2 + U[ϕϕ[t]]);

sigma = 1*10^-4;
a0 = 1;
b0 = 1;
c0 = 1;
phi0 = 0;
phik = 3*10^-4;


w = .1;
h = (1/2*phik^2 + U[phi0]) (1 - 1/sigma*(1/2*phik^2 + U[phi0])) - l;

Show[ContourPlot3D[{c0*x*y + b0*x*z + a0*y*z == h*a0*b0*c0}, {x, -w, 
   w}, {y, -w, w}, {z, -w, w}], 
 Graphics3D[InfiniteLine[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]]]
x = Sqrt[(h*a0*b0*c0)/(a0 + b0 + c0)]

ka = x;
kb = x;
kc = x;

(*equations*)

tmin = 0;
tmax = 15000;
sol01 = NDSolve[{aa[t] bb[t] cc[t] ϕϕ''[
        t] + (aa'[t] bb[t] cc[t] + bb'[t] aa[t] cc[t] + 
         aa[t] bb[t] cc'[t]) ϕϕ'[t] + 
      aa[t] bb[t] cc[t] D[U[ϕϕ[t]], ϕϕ[t]] == 0
    , (aa'[t] bb[t] cc[t] + aa[t] bb'[t] cc[t] + 
       aa[t] bb[t] cc'[t]) == 
     nn[t]*Sqrt[3*den (1 - den/sigma) - 3*l] (aa[t] bb[t] cc[t])
    , -aa'[t] cc'[t] bb[t] - aa''[t] bb[t] cc[t] - 
      aa[t] bb[t] cc''[t] + aa[t] bb'[t] cc'[t] + 
      aa[t] cc[t] bb''[t] + aa[t] bb[t] cc''[t] == 0
    , -aa[t] bb'[t] cc'[t] - aa[t] cc[t] bb''[t] - 
      aa[t] bb[t] cc''[t] + aa'[t] bb'[t] cc[t] + 
      bb[t] cc[t] aa''[t] + aa[t] cc[t] bb''[t] == 0
    , nn[0] == 1, aa[0] == a0, bb[0] == b0, cc[0] == c0, aa'[0] == ka,
     bb'[0] == kb, 
    cc'[0] == kc, ϕϕ[0] == phi0, ϕϕ'[0] == phik, 
    WhenEvent[
     3*l > 0.995*3*(1/2 (ϕϕ'[t])^2 + 
         1/2 m^2 (ϕϕ[t])^2), {nn[t] -> -1, tr = Re[t], 
      Print["Retorno en t =", t]}]
    }, {ϕϕ, aa, bb, cc, nn}, {t, tmin, tmax}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> {nn}, AccuracyGoal -> 7, PrecisionGoal -> 7, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
```

NDSolve::reinitfail: Unable to reinitialize the system at t = 12085.732303153314` within specified tolerances.